# Firebase auth: unable to auth with Google on my own domain

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I have added Firebase auth to my Angular 16 app using @angular/fire, and I am able to auth running on localhost using Google, and on the Firebase domain at https://example.firebaseapp.com.

When I visit my app at that domain, all good.

But when I visit https://example.com, which is configured in Firebase to point to my app, the auth does not succeed. In fact, the auth redirects still to the Firebase domain to perform the auth, and then redirects back to my custom domain.

I have read all sorts of documentation, including the most hopeful telling me I need to configure the callback URL in the identity provider in GCP Identity Platform, but I have checked every page and there is no option to configure this.

What is it I need to do to get auth to work on my custom domain? If that is configuring the auth domain, how do I do that?

### UPDATE

It seems that logging in to my domain works on Chrome for macOS.

But fails everywhere else:

- Chrome for iOS: FAIL
- Safari for macOS and iOS: FAIL

I can log in to the Firebase domain, as I say, but who wants to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You must [configure the authorized domains](https://dev.to/clericcoder/how-i-solved-firebase-authunauthorized-domain-domain-is-not-authorized-error-problem-using-the-vite-development-tool-2md7) in your Firebase project settings in order for Firebase Authentication to function with a custom domain. When you include your custom domain in the list of authorized domains, Firebase Authentication will redirect authentication requests to your custom domain rather than the default Firebase domain. This ensures that authentication functions smoothly on your custom domain.

For your updated status, it may be because of various factors, including `browser configurations`, `cookie settings`, or `browser-imposed restrictions` if authentication fails on some systems and browsers.

It might also be helpful to examine the error messages or logs presented by Firebase Authentication or the developer tools of your browser. This can provide you with more detailed information about the causes of the failures.